# Mysql concat unequal table field

Tags: php, mysql, select, concatenation

why I can't Select a row of a table with an unequal concat construction? I'll show you an example.

### Table1

| **id** | **area** |

| 1 | items_labeling_small |

| 2 | items_labeling_big |

### Table2

| **id** | **area** | **kat** |

| 1 | small | labeling |

| 2 | big | labeling |

> SELECT Table1.area FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.area != CONCAT('items_', Table2.kat, '_', Table2.area)

No results have to be shown, because both are matching with the concat construction. But they're shown in result. I've no idea why.. and how I can change the query that it works.

Comment: Please stop using comma based ancient join method. Use explicit `join` syntax instead.

Comment: Also, in your code add a `and table1.id = table2.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are show because each row don't match the other  so you have the rows that not match

```
    SELECT Table1.area 
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON  Table1.area != CONCAT('items_', Table2.kat, '_', Table2.area)
```

could be you want a not in

```
    SELECT Table1.area 
    FROM Table1 
    where  Table1.area NOT IN (

        SELECT CONCAT('items_', Table2.kat, '_', Table2.area)

        FROM Table2

    )
```

and as  a suggestion you should not use the (old) implict join sintax based on where clause  ...use explicit join sintax ..

Comment: You made my sunday! Thank you @scaisEdge